# Windows IoT Raspberry Pi GPIO with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, raspberry-pi, gpio, windowsiot

I am trying to just use a small program to make sure I have everything setup correctly. However, I am getting errors (see comments) for everything that is referencing "GPIO"
Also, I have already referenced the "Windows IoT Extensions for UWP".
- Thank you and any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Imports Windows.Devices.Gpio  'Imports statement is unnecessary

Public NotInheritable Class MainPage
Inherits Page
Private gpio
Private pin As GpioPin 'ERROR: GpioPin is not defined
Private Const LED_PIN = 18

Private Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button.Click
    Call TurnLedOnOff()
End Sub

Private Sub TurnLedOnOff()

        'Check if gpio was already initialied
        If gpio Is Nothing Then
            gpio = GpioController.GetDefault 'ERROR: GpioController is not declared 
        End If

        'Check if LED's pin was already initialied
        If pin Is Nothing Then
            pin = gpio.OpenPin(LED_PIN)
            pin.Write(GpioPinValue.Low) 'ERROR: Not Declared
            pin.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output) 'ERROR: Not Declared
        End If

        'Read pin status and invert state
        If pin.Read = GpioPinValue.High Then 'ERROR: Not Declared
            pin.Write(GpioPinValue.Low) 'ERROR: Not Declared
        Else
            pin.Write(GpioPinValue.High) 'ERROR: Not Declared
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Looks like you've got an development environment issue. Are you sure you have windows SDK 10586 installed?

Answer (score -1):

try

```
If gpio Is Nothing Then
    gpio = GpioController.GetDefault.openpin(LED_PIN) 
end if
```